# SSRS Subscription Fail: 5.3.3 Unrecognized command

Tags: reporting-services, smtp, subscription

We have many subscriptions and sometimes one fails with an error like the following. It was bearable, but now it is ervery day for many times.

Even though the LastRunTime of the subscription was:
**2020-10-26** 09:41:55.827

Ther error states a differen datetime:

```
Failure sending mail: Syntax error, command unrecognized. 
The server response was: 5.3.3 Unrecognized command '16.Oct.2020'Mail will not beresent.
```

--> **16.Oct.2020**

Sometimes a report subscription runs successfully and a few minutes later it fails with that error.

If I change the schedule time and restart the job for the subscriptionID the sending succeeds. And later it can fail again.

Can please anyone help fixing this?

Comment: Is this a data driven subscription or standard subscription?

Comment: We do not have Enterprise, so it is not data-driven.